# Not being able to style <StripeCheckout>

Tags: sass

This is the html:

```
<StripeCheckout className='payBtn' />
```

And this is how it looks right now:
[image]

And this is the `.scss` for it:

```
.payBtn {
        display: block;
        background-color: rgba(160, 255, 223, 0.596);
        color: black;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: 200;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 1rem 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        cursor: pointer;
    
        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(114, 250, 205, 0.699);
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to make it look like:
[what it needs to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v9ia.png)

Everything else on the page is styled according to the stylesheet. Even the size of the button of `pay with card` is. But the colors and stuff are not changing. Any help would be appreciated, thanks :D